# optimal coverage of a polygon using rectangles

Tags: geometry, convex-optimization, computational-geometry

I'm looking for an algorithm that can help me find optimal/ or close to that for finding coordinates to place a set number of rectangles in order to maximum coverage of a polygon.

For example, let's say you have a convex polygon that can be put in a $1 \times 1$ meter square. I have $4$ rectangles which are $0.70 \times 0.40$ and they can be placed anywhere on the polygon and in any direction. Is there a way to calculate the optimal way to position the rectangle covers over the polygon in order to maximize the area of polygon which is covered?

Ideally I won't need to assume the polygon is convex but for a start I don't mind. I also wanted to note out the the covers are allowed to be outside the borders of the polygon, they can be anywhere I like them to be. I really appreciate the help.